# Is it possible to include arguments in slash commands (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently trying to build a discord.js bot that links to an NBA api in order to output statistics when requested. I am able to connect to the api and output my results eg. /seasons will output all seasons on record.

What i am now trying to achieve is a command such as /player-stats [player name] which will then output the stats of the requested player but i am unable to find a way to register the argument (players name) along with the command (/player-stats).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take the message and split it up into the parts you need

Comment: Are you asking how to access it, or how to create it?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about making the slash commands have arguments, look at the various docs provided by both discord.js and Discord itself that have your answer for you. Perhaps you should check out discord.js' handy [slash command builder](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/stable/class/SlashCommandBuilder) utility they created to make it easy to create slash commands, with whatever args you want.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add arguments in interaction commands.

If you are new you can use a gui for making slash commands also

https://slash-commands-gui.androz2091.fr/

You can get help from here also
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXehoXnFxPM

Comment: The website is for new persons only!